# NextJS 13 app directory | Meta tags not included in generated static html. opengraph not found by crawlers

Tags: next.js, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, next.js13

I'm facing a problem with meta tags for nextjs 13.2.4. I followed the official documentation at https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/metadata.
No matter if I use `export const metadata = { ... }` or `export async function generateMetadata`, the meta tags are not included in the static html code. Instead, it is included in the `self.__next_f.push(` which is not found by opengraph crawlers.
I tried putting the `export metadata` statement inside the layout.tsx, the page.tsx, nothing seems to work.

E.g. [facebook sharing debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) won't show the opengraph preview.
It shows the html looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="__next_error__">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills-c67a75d1b6f99dc8.js" nomodule=""></script>
</head>
...
```

the og meta data tags are inside in the `<script>(self.__next_f=self.__next_f||[]).push([0]) ...`

Someone has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Okay after 3 days of troubleshooting...
The problem was, that my layout.tsx used a client component which made use of the hook `useSearchParams`. This hook apparently broke static rendering completely so the meta tags were not statically generated in the index.html.

Just removing the hook `useSearchParams` did the trick